# Is sandbox the way to try out certain extensions now (instead of Cividemo)?

Tags: civievent

CiviDiscount isn't among the extensions configurable in demo, is that b/c 1) it isn't stable enough now (4.6), or 2) there's another way to test it, besides installing it locally (e.g sandbox)? 
A second question - there's code in CiviEvent registration relating to some other form of discount, is that functional code and if so, how is it configurable?

Comment: I've answered the title question below, but there are really three questions in your post (How do I try out extensions? What happened to CiviDiscount? What's this code in CiviEvent?). The [StackExchange format](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour) is a Q&A model, and wants you to select one "right" answer for each question you ask. You might want to post separate questions to get clear answers to each?

Comment: AFAIK CiviDiscount is not yet viable for recent civi versions. there are a few people looking at various parts of it. I have pinged them for an idea on timeframe and will update if i get one.

Answer (score 3):

To try out extensions, I recommend setting up [CiviCRM Buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit). CiviCRM Buildkit makes the task of spinning up CiviCRM test instances (in multiple flavours) much easier, then you can try any extension you like on it - and have a more complete environment to test in.

- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is yes. If you want to try CiviCRM with some additional extensions you will have to create your sandbox. And as Chris mentioned, CiviCRM BuildKit is a great help.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about CiviDiscount. It has now been updated to work with 4.6 though I understand a couple of issues that were problems also in earlier versions are not yet fixed but might be by next week.
Version 3 is now listed here as compatible with 4.6 https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount
Still worth doing testing on a dev site though ;-)